# Query for the scenario

Tags: teradata

I have to implement a query where the scenario is something like below;

```
Col_1 Col_2  Col_3  Col_4  Col_5
A       AB    AC     AD     AE
B       BC    BD     BE     ? 
C       CD    CE      ?      ?
D       DE     ?       ?      ?
E        ?     ?       ?      ?
```

Any help on the below is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Trying to implement this using Rows 1 following and 1 following.

Comment: Can you show actual data? What's your Teradata release?

Comment: Hi Dieter,
As of now, i don't have the actual data. My teradata version is 14.01.0.04.

Comment: What's the data type? Is a result `AB` a concatenated string or what?

Comment: Yes, all are  varchar field.

Comment: And what's your Teradata release?

Comment: Database Version: Teradata 14.00.0715  14.00.07.15
ODBC 14.00.00.05

Comment: How is the data sorted, by `col_1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need different `rows` for each column:

```
select
   col_1
  ,col_1 || min(col_1) over (order by ... rows between 1 following and 1 following)
  ,col_1 || min(col_1) over (order by ... rows between 2 following and 2 following)
  ,col_1 || min(col_1) over (order by ... rows between 3 following and 3 following)
  ,col_1 || min(col_1) over (order by ... rows between 4 following and 4 following)
```

Comment: Thanks Dieter,
That's working fine. I have one doubt and has always been. How does min(col1) over.. work here. max(col1) over .. also gives the required result. What's the difference.

Comment: @user3901666: This is a way to mimic Standatd SQL's `LEAD(col_1,n)` in Teradata. As the size of the window is exactly one row `MIN` and `MAX` will return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

{

```
SELECT CHR(64+LEVEL) AS A,
DECODE(SIGN( 4 - LEVEL ) , -1, '?',CHR(64+LEVEL)||CHR(65 +LEVEL)) B,
DECODE(SIGN( 3 - LEVEL ) , -1, '?',CHR(64+LEVEL)||CHR(66 +LEVEL)) C,
DECODE(SIGN( 2 - LEVEL ) , -1, '?',CHR(64+LEVEL)||CHR(67 +LEVEL)) D,
DECODE(sign( 1 - level ) , -1, '?',chr(64+level)||chr(68 +level)) E
 from dual connect by level <6;
```

}
this above is using oracle 10g, other db should have some other strategy.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dieter, 
Its working perfectly.
@nirjhar--don't know exactly how to implement that in teradata.Thanks for your help.